# Can I scan and print integers simultaneously in C?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

While trying to use scanf and printf functions in C serially in a for loop, the program is closing. I am using CODE::BLOCKS on Windows 7. Following is the code. Why does this happen?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,A[i];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        printf(" %d",A[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `A[i]` is undefined because `i` is uninitialized.  You should write `A[10]` instead.

Comment: You should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.

Comment: The following replaced statement is working.   int i=0,A[i];

Comment: `int i=0,A[i];` invokes undefined behavior.  Use `int i=10,A[i];` or better `int i; int  A[10];`

Comment: Both void main() and int main(void) functions take no arguments but  int main(void) also doesnt return any integer?

Comment: @VikranthInti, `int main(void)` does return an integer.  See, my code below, where I have included `return 0;` at the end to denote normal program termination.

Comment: @BatCoder, I wish to know further the difference between both the ways, since coding could be done generally  in more than 1 way. As MikeCAT mentioned, is it the case with coding style and standards only?

Comment: @MikeCAT, I tried using void main() also and it is working. If it is illegal, it should show warning or error message. But the program is executing. Please help why does this happen.

Comment: @Vikranth Inti " it should show warning or error message." --> No.  As MikeCAT said, " implementation-defined " means it may work on you compiler/platform, but since it is non-standard, it may not work elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code that you have posted, `A[i]` is undefined because `i` has not been initialized.  Besides, you need to make sure that the size of array `A[]` is `10` because you are iterating over `10` elements in your for loop.  Please refer the modified code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, A[10];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        printf(" %d",A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `A[10]` is an array of `10` elements.  Besides, note that the return type of `main()` is `int` (and not `void`).  Consequently, a statement `return 0` has been added at the bottom.

Working code [**here**](http://ideone.com/zDNUW5).